# How to add to array in mongo db collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good evening,

I have my model

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const widgetSchema = new Schema({
    city: {
        type: String
    }
})

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    widgets: [widgetSchema]
})


const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

And my question is how can I add elements to the widget array?
Should I use an update or what?
I think, firstly I  need to find user document:

```html
app.post('/addwidget', async (req, res) => {
    const { city } = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({"name": "1"});
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

and thank what? Is there method like push or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
  try {
    const user = await Research.findOneAndUpdate({ name: '1' }, { $push: { widgets: { city: 'viking' }} })
    if (user) return user;
    else return false;
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use $push or $addToSet to add new item to the widgets array :

```
app.post('/addwidget', async (req, res) => {
    const { city } = req.body; // 
    try {
        const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({"name": "1"} , { $push: { widgets: city }});
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

or :

```
app.post('/addwidget', async (req, res) => {
    const { city } = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({"name": "1"} , { $addToSet : {widgets: city }});
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc: [Adding Subdocs to Arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#adding-subdocs-to-arrays), you can use [MongooseArray.prototype.push()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-push)

E.g.

```js
app.post('/addwidget', async (req, res) => {
  const { city } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ name: '1' });
    user.widgets.push({ city: 'viking' });
    await user.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```